# The Network Adapter could not establish the connectionDSRA0010E: SQL State = null, Error Code = 17,002″

Tags: java

I am facing below  issue.
1- I have data source on my local websphere6.1 and when i do test connection from web console server ,it was successful but when i tried to do the same from my application code it giving me error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connectionDSRA0010E: SQL State = null, Error Code = 17,002
```

Note : I am connecting to remote oracle db in my machine , I have only raid,toad & web sphere installed.

I have already tried following things but issue is yet not resolved.

1. Replace my server names with the ip addresses.
2. Change minimum connection setting from web sphere server  configuration
3. The same configuration is running to my other colleague but issue is occurring only on my laptop.

Please any body help me.
Advance thank you

Comment: Post some code.  It's hard to debug sight-unseen!

Answer (score 1):

Some things you can try, seeing your error:-

-> Verify that oracledb is started, also verify the port db is listening on is correct.

-> If you have firewall in between and you can disable it, disable it and try. Or else try adding the WAS ports in authorized lists of firewall.

Comment: 1- Same application is running on my college's system so i do not think there will be any db port listening issue.
2-I have tried by disable firewall and then running the program but still facing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of searching and did lots of trick , i resolved this issue and this solution is Formatting my machine.
Some time there might be issue with network adapter due to this it create problem .  I have tried below thing before formatting my machine.
 1- Disable my symantic anti-virus but not work.
2- Adding oracle db ip in antivirus configuration and allow all traffic.
3-Tried to change from server admin console by changing (min connection ,max connection , componenet managed authentication
4- Finally ,un-install RAID/websphere . Still again problem persist.
I have spent lot of time and do Much R&D but finally solution come by formatting my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue after that I've changed the database port that I used to connect at the bd. Check on whitch port your db has been started.

You can check the official IBM developer network issue at:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014687717

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the JVM argument through the WAS Admin console while connecting the JNDI connection. Below is value :

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Path to set JVM:

1. Go to the server and select Websphere application server  and select server name like server1
2. Select Java and Process Management at the right side
3. Select Process definition
4. Select Java Virtual Machine

Enter above value (`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`) in Generic JVM arguments and Save it and restart the server.

It resolved my problem!